# IE - Radio button checked with styles makes the page scrolling down

Tags: html, css

I am encountering a problem with a radio button in IE 11.

I have a simple radio button that makes my content scroll down once checked.
Without any styles applied, there is no problem. But with, the problem is back.

Does it have something to do with the IE render engine?

```
    .switch {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 34px;
        height: 18px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        cursor: pointer;
        outline: 0;
        height: 18px;
        top: 5px;
        background-color: $grey-light;
        box-shadow: $switch-shadow;

        &::before {
            content: " ";
            position: absolute;
            left: 2px;
            top: 2px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin: 0;
            outline: none;
            height: 14px;
            width: 14px;
            background: white;
            transition: background-color .08s ease-in;
        }


        &.active::before {
            background-color: $green-dark;
            left: 18px;
            transition: background-color .08s ease-in, left .08s ease-in;
        }

        &.inactive::before {
            background-color: $grey-dark;
            left: 2px;
            transition: background-color .08s ease-in, left .08s ease-in;
        }

        input[type=checkbox] {
            // display: none;
            visibility: hidden;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT.

I forgot to precise that the scrolling box (`flex: 1`) has a parent which has `display: flex`.

Comment: Can you add fiddle?

Comment: Unfortunetly, I cannot. This code is from a huge app... @DmytroLishtvan

Comment: It would be hard to say what causes the issue with just a piece of css code, see if you can recreate it in a codepen or fiddle